# How to sort a custom wordpress query by combination of meta values?

Tags: wp-query, sort

I'm trying to build a custom query that's a combination of custom key values. For example, with the code below I'm able to sort my posts by how much money they've received (paidusd) and how much tips they've received (totaltips). This code is working great.

But what I'd like to do is add another sort for "most profitable" which would be the ratio of paidusd to totaltips. Where would I perform that division equation? I'm stumped.

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks!!!!

```
if ( $_GET['sort'] == 'mostexpensive'){
    //query_posts('&meta_key=paidbtc&orderby=meta_value');
    $args = array(
                   'meta_key' => 'paidusd',
                   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                   'posts_per_page' => 10,
                   'paged' => $paged
                   );
    query_posts($args);
}

if ( $_GET['sort'] == 'mosttipped'){
    $args = array(
                   'meta_key' => 'totaltips',
                   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                   'posts_per_page' => 10,
                   'paged' => $paged
                   );
    query_posts($args);
}
```

Comment: OK, so I'm halfway there. My solution is to run 2 loops - the first loop is to make a multidimensional array for the post ID and the post's profitability. So I have an array called "$idsandscores" that looks like this:

    [209] => 0.29090909090909
    [478] => 2.65
    [231] => 27.84
    [133] => 29 

So my question is, how do I make a wordpress query ordered by the IDs in my $idsandposts array?

Comment: Edit 2 - looks like I found it! http://wordpress.org/support/topic/order-by-page_in-array-sequence

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do is possible-- MySQL can do math-- but `WP_Query` can't handle this natively. You'd need to apply a filter or two. You would end up sorting on generated values which is not especially efficient. That is, MySQL, would read all of the rows in the table for those two keys, do some math, and then sort.

My advice would be to store a third key-- say, `profitability`-- when you save the post keys, and then sort on that instead of trying to generate this is SQL. Something, very crudely, like this:

```
function generate_profitability_wpse_138683($meta_id,$object_id,$meta_key,$_meta_value) {

  if ('paidusd' === $meta_key) {
    $tips = get_post_meta($object_id,'totaltips');
    if (!empty($tips)) {
      $profit = (int)$_meta_value/(int)$tips;
    }
  } elseif ('totaltips' === $meta_key) {
    $paid = get_post_meta($object_id,'paidusd');
    if (!empty($paid)) {
      $profit = (int)$paid/(int)$_meta_value;
    }
  }

  if (!empty($profit)) {
    update_post_meta($object_id,'profitability',$profit);
  }
}
add_action('updated_post_meta','generate_profitability_wpse_138683',10,4);
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually decided to go this route and it's working great. I had assumed though that it was bad practice to store something in the database when it can be computed on the fly. (I have nothing to back that up, just a hunch.) anyway thanks!

Comment: The Core "transient" system is essentially "storing thing in the database what can be computed on the fly". What is bad practice is computing on the fly when that is _slower_ than caching in the database. "Transients" would be another similar option, by the way.